# Tensorflow module not found in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

On my jupyter notebook when I run:

```
!pip3 install tensorflow
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in /home/bluegoblin/.virtualenvs/tf2Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.3.1)
```

So, this means I do have tensorflow installed on my virtual environment.

But then when I try to import it using `import tensorflow as tf` on the same notebook, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

The problem only exists inside jupyter notebook, outside the notebook the import works without any problem.
I am running Python3.8 in Xubuntu, and I'm not using ananconda.

Comment: What virtual environment are you using? when I set up a jupyter kernel with pipenv I use this:   pipenv --$pyVersion install ipykernel
  venvDir=`pipenv --venv`
  projectName=`basename $venvDir`
  pipenv run python -m ipykernel install --user --name="${projectName}"

Comment: I created virtual environment using the venv wrapper command 'mkvirtualenv tf2Env'. Then I used: 'python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf2Env' to load it into jupyter

Comment: do other modules installed using this method work properly?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that at first. Yes the problem exists for all modules. I just tried that with pillow.

Comment: Then I would guess that you're not adding the modules to the search path of the jupyter kernel. This script sets up the environment for a pipenv virtual environment; perhaps there's something in there that will help: https://github.com/txoof/develtools/blob/master/pipenv_jupyter.sh

Answer (score 0):

Create virtual environment and install Tensorflow

```
#Install virtualenv
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
#Create virtual environment name: venv
virtualenv venv
#Activate venv
source venv/bin/activate
#Install tensorflow
venv$ pip3 install tensorflow
#Install Jupyter notebook
venv$ pip3 install notebook
# Launch jupyter notebook
venv$ jupyter notebook
```